# Form not showing in sencha 2.2

Tags: sencha-touch-2.2

I'm able to show the form inside the container. I used to add it like this...

```
var form = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    fullscreen: true,
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            name: 'name',
            label: 'Name'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'emailfield',
            name: 'email',
            label: 'Email'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'passwordfield',
            name: 'password',
            label: 'Password'
        }
    ]
});

Ext.define('MyApp.view.Login',{
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    alias: 'widget.login',

    config:{
        items:[
            form
        ]
    }
});
```

The first part of the code was taken from [sencha 2.2 docs](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.Panel), but still got no results...

I've also tried to use Ext.define and assigning an alias to use the xtype inside items, but nothing happens.

Is is ok to use a Container to wrap the formpanel? or should I move to Panel?

BTW, I have my project configured with Sencha Touch 2.2 and PhoneGap 2.9 and the problem occurs when I tested on xcode

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You problem may stem from trying to use `Ext.define` to define a class, mixed with `Ext.create` to create an instance.  Why are you trying to wrap the form in a container?  You should be able to just move your `items` from the form into your `login` panel, and have that class extend `Ext.form.Panel`, like this:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.Login', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    xtype: 'widget.login',
    config: {    
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                name: 'name',
                label: 'Name'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'emailfield',
                name: 'email',
                label: 'Email'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'passwordfield',
                name: 'password',
                label: 'Password'
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

If you must wrap, then try just defining a new class for your form as an extension of `Ext.form.Panel` (rather than using an instance), then use `{ xtype: 'loginform' }` in the `items` of your `MyApp.view.Login`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer... The idea of wrap the form in a container is because I did not want to add my form on items, just to have my class as small as possible. Anyway, I ended up adding my fomr directly to my Main class items but using an xtype fieldset (plus its item array of course).